# Trimming the white space in an image using PIL in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am doing **handwritten digit recognition** using **SciKit-learn** so for that I need to crop the clicked picture so I have prepared a template on the Word.
Now what I want is the image to be cropped along the border so that I can crop it further to extract the digits.

Sample Image is given below:

[image]

For cropping the image I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/sigilioso/2957026) Code.

Below is the parent Image from which the above rectangle has been cropped:
[image]

> Note: The parent image has a border too(which is not visible in the image) so trimming the white space might help in getting a modified parent image so that predefined (height, width) would be almost same for various crops to be done on the image.

Comment: What are your attempts to crop the desired rect ?

Comment: @ZdaR I am using the mentioned code only to crop the given rectangle further(by giving crop_type='top/middle/bottom') but I am getting the white space around the border which I don't want

Comment: Then you need to specifically define the cropping bounds.

Comment: Is there no way to just simply crop the image along the border.
Because that would be helpful for me in handling any image and just trim the white spaces so that predefined (width, height) for cropping would be same for every image.
Actually I have to do various crops on a single image. You can look at question for the parent image from which the rect has been cropped. @ZdaR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply this pipeline: convert to grayscale -> apply thresholding (convert to white & black) -> find contours -> choose the contours of the right shape.

Here is example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2

BLACK_THRESHOLD = 200
THIN_THRESHOLD = 10
ANNOTATION_COLOUR = (222,0,222)

img = cv2.imread('template.png')
orig = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=BLACK_THRESHOLD, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Optional: save thesholded image
cv2.imwrite("temp_thres.png", thresh)

# Find contours on the thresholded image
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
for cont in contours:
    # Find bounding rectangle of a contour
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    # Skip thin contours (vertical and horizontal lines)
    if h<THIN_THRESHOLD or w<THIN_THRESHOLD:
        continue
    # Does the countour has the right shape (roughly four times longer than high)?
    if 3*h<w<5*h:
        roi = orig[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite("four_letters.png",roi)

    # Optional: draw annotations
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),ANNOTATION_COLOUR,3)

# Optional: save annotated image
cv2.imwrite("temp_cont.png",img)
```

(You can delete the three optional steps. They are just for generating images `temp_thres.png` and `temp_cont.png`.)

Input image `template.png`:

[image: Input image: blank template]

Thresholded image `temp_thres.png`:

[image: White and black thresholded image]

Found contours `temp_cont.png`:

[image: Original image with two regions annotated]

Four letter space `four_letters.png`:

[image: Cropped four letter space]

Comment: Amazingly explained Kudos! just got it working.
And i am facing a problem while extracting these contours it is returning kind of duplicates. So should i post another question? Would you be able to help me?
Thank you Cheers! @Andriy Makukha

Comment: If suppose i am drawing contour around a digit let say, then it starts making contour according to the hierarchy. What if I want the contour around the border only so there will be no noise in the area enclosed by the contour. How can it be done ? Can you suggest me any documentation or links?
Thank You @Andiry Makukha